# How to group users as A, B or both

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

If I have data like this:

```
user + tag
-----|-----
bob  |  A
bob  |  A
bob  |  B
tom  |  A
tom  |  A
amy  |  B
amy  |  B
jen  |  A
jen  |  A
```

For millions of users, I want to know how many users have tag A, B and both. It's the 'both' case I'm stuck on.

In this case, the answer is:

```
Both: 1
A only: 2
B only: 1
```

I don't need to return the user ID's, only the counts. I'm using BigQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one solution, using the `SOME` and `EVERY` functions:

```
SELECT
  SUM(category == 'both') AS both_count,
  SUM(category == 'A') AS a_count,
  SUM(category == 'B') AS b_count
FROM (
  SELECT
    name,
    CASE WHEN SOME(tag == 'A') AND SOME(tag == 'B') THEN 'both' 
         WHEN EVERY(tag == 'A') THEN 'A' 
         WHEN EVERY(tag == 'B') THEN 'B'
         ELSE 'none' END AS category
  FROM 
    (SELECT 'bob' as name, 'A' as tag),
    (SELECT 'bob' as name, 'A' as tag),
    (SELECT 'bob' as name, 'B' as tag),
    (SELECT 'tom' as name, 'A' as tag),
    (SELECT 'tom' as name, 'A' as tag),
    (SELECT 'amy' as name, 'B' as tag),
    (SELECT 'amy' as name, 'B' as tag),
    (SELECT 'jen' as name, 'A' as tag),
    (SELECT 'jen' as name, 'A' as tag)
  GROUP BY name)
```

Comment: @zbinsd this query works for millions of users, what's your issue? You simply replace the static `FROM` of the example with your query.

Comment: Should work for millions users, but you might need to replace GROUP BY with GROUP EACH BY in case of millions users.
Now if you also have millions records per-user, you might benefit from first doing GROUP EACH BY name, tag to remove duplicate records.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the syntax of google bigquery, but here is a sql based solution to the question.

```
    select a.tag_desc, count(distinct a.user) as total
    from (
    select coalesce(tA.user,tB.user) as user
      , tA.tag
      , tB.tag
      , case 
          when tA.tag is not null and tB.tag is not null then 'Both'
          when tA.tag is not null and tB.tag is null then 'A Only'
          when tA.tag is null and tB.tag is not null then 'B Only'
        end as tag_desc
    from table tA
      full outer join table tB
        on tA.user = tB.user
        and tB.tag = B
    where tA.tag = 'A'
    ) a
```

There is a subquery joining your dataset back to itself with a full outer join.  This will allow you to evaluate the two conditions (A and B) together.  There is a case statement to define the three results. In the outer query, I count the users for each case statement result.

Comment: I double checked the bigquery documentation, and it appears to support full outer join.  This, or something similar, should work.

Comment: Re-reading the question, I see that the sample data includes duplicate records.  My query doesn't take that into account.